# I have two different SharePoint picture libaries showing the same thing. How do I get them to show correctly?

Tags: image, sharepoint, libraries

I have two different picture libaries showing the same thing. How do I get them to show correctly?

[image: sharepoint 2013 picture libraries]

Answer (score -1):

1)Delete one.
2) back up and delete one
3) back up delete them all then restore one
4)leave them alone and never talk about again.
Hope this helps

Comment: Are you being serious or sarcastic? Your answer isn't clear at all.